# How to change a Button widget's text size?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been looking all over Google and SO for something that might help me with this seemingly simple problem.

I have a button in Tkinter and I want its weight to be bold.  I've tried this:

```
test = Button(..., text="Test", font=("Arial",10,"bold"), command=...)
```

And this:

```
test = Button(..., text="Test", font="Arial 10 bold", command=...)
```

But both return `unknown option -font` errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you please cut and paste the whole error you get? `font` is most definitely an option for the tkinter Button class.

My guess is, when you think you are creating a tkinter Button widget, you're creating something different -- maybe a ttk Button widget which doesn't support the font attribute.

Comment: Wow, thank you!  That was it.  I was apparently doing `from Tkinter import *` and `from ttk import Button`. I removed the second line and all is well.  May I ask what the difference between `Tkinter` and `ttk` is because I apparently got those lines from some online tutorial somewhere.  Might I say that the `ttk` button looks a whole lot better.  Is there a way to style the `Tkinter` button?

Comment: @noblerare: this is exactly why doing global imports is bad. If you had done "import ttk; import Tkinter as tk; ... ttk.Button(...)` the problem would have been more obvious.

Comment: @noblerare: the difference between tk and ttk is that the latter are "styled", and generally look a bit nicer looking. You lose some flexibility in exchange for a nicer appearance. You can change the font using styles. It's not very well documented, but a good place to start is tkdocs.com